# How do I retrieve a PDF of an invoice in QuickBooks API?

Tags: c#, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Using IPP.NET SDK v2.0.1, need to get a PDF version of an invoice as a file, just like it would have been e-mailed to a customer.

I have the `Invoice` object retrieved from the service already.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is not yet supported in QBO V3 API service. This feature should be included in future API releases.

Attachment is not same as what you are looking for. But still, you can have a look if it serves your purpose.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/attachments

This feature was available in QBO V2( it is deprecated now).
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbo_v2/0400_qbo_v2_reference/invoice#Retrieving_an_Invoice_as_PDF

Thanks

Comment: That's bad news. Added follow-up question for e-mail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953809/how-do-i-email-an-invoice-from-quickbooks-api

Comment: It has been 6 months.. Not holding my breath.. FYI, Xero has this feature in current API.