# Quickbooks PHP Web Connector API:Saving PDF of an invoice using the API

Tags: php, pdf, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml

In Quickbooks 2015, there is a feature in within a job's invoice to save/print to PDF file for document printing purposes

Similar to this question:
[How do I retrieve a PDF of an invoice in QuickBooks API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942830/how-do-i-retrieve-a-pdf-of-an-invoice-in-quickbooks-api)

[image: Screenshot]

Results in:

[image: PDF]

Is there any way to automate this task using the Quickbooks PHP api?
there isn't a qbxml request for it but I was wondering if there is something else I can use

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to automate this task using the Quickbooks PHP api?

No.

You can do this in QuickBooks Online, but QuickBooks for Windows does not support saving the PDFs outside of the UI.

Instead, you can query for all of the information, and use a PDF library to build your own PDF.

- https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
- http://www.fpdf.org/
- http://www.tcpdf.org/

Comment: Hi, Can you please guide me how we can make pdf of invoice using PHP api in quickbook online. Thanks.

Comment: Please go read the documentation, and if you're still stuck you can ask a NEW QUESTION on StackOverflow, showing what you've tried already.