# QuickBooks c# save pdf invoice

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have really been struggling with Inuit QuickBooks desktop. I have built a lovely c# windows form for my client to interact with QuickBooks desktop version. Everything works really well except:

I create invoices etc. But once created I need to use the clients QuickBooks invoice as a .pdf to attach to an email.

I can't find anywhere that can do a programatic save for the pdf once I create an invoice, to save it to the file structure.

I can see a lot of questions but nobody seems to have done it. Has anyone else had this problem and what was the solution?

Comment: i found this which might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942830/how-do-i-retrieve-a-pdf-of-an-invoice-in-quickbooks-api and this https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/invoice#get-an-invoice-as-pdf

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. that second on is QuickBooks online, which won't work:( the first one I'll explore. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually.. that post is from 2014 and the link in it is a 404:( maybe it just can't be done, but as I say to my Devs - there's always a way. May not be perfect but always a way..

Comment: That’s no good, perhaps there is some sort of a render that will return a byte array you can use?

Comment: Yup it's returns the invoice as XML.. I may have to resort to using interop and recreate the template in word but that seems crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

I create a PDF from the C# application using DevExpress XtraReports tool and it's designed to look exactly like a QuickBooks invoice. Then I call the method that saves it as a PDF. You can also use Crystal Reports for Visual Studio or Microsoft RDLC Report Designer for a free tool.

If you must send it from Quickbooks, the only option you have is to set the IsToBeEmailed property and then email it in QB from the File-SendForms menu.

Comment: Thanks. Can the second option be done programatically from the application? It sounds like maybe I could set up an email for the application to send to itself and then save it back to the file structure.